# Create an adjacent rectangle while extruding the wall

Tags: inkscape

I want to create an adjacent rectangle while expanding other rectangle's wall. Lets say this is our first draw

[image: first draw]

I want  to expand its right side while keeping the wall, just like that

[image: second draw]

how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer has been deleted]

Comment: I'm pretty sure based on the second example image, OP wanted to keep that vertical wall in place, like this: [example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lnil.gif) — I don't use Inkscape, so I did the gif in Illustrator.

Comment: You have two objects right? that could be done, let me just improve the answer.

Comment: Yea I cheated by just duplicating the object, locking it and selecting the top points and then moved them. — I should say I was just guessing.... so I don't know if you want to wait for OP to confirm or deny what I was saying before you make changes.

Comment: @Joonas Okay. I think I should improve my answer. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @joonas many thanks for the answer. is there a way to do it without a dublicate item. iam asking because iam gonna do it many times and idk what to do with duplicated items at the end.

Comment: @Kai thare is no direct way to do so but you may add a vertical line segment or you may just add a rectangle instead of extending any side or duplicating.

Comment: User @Moini noted yesterday in his comment to a deleted post that dragging corners holding Ctrl+Alt makes the needed extension to the right direction also in case the shape is rotated. It's in Inscape reference https://inkscape.org/doc/keys092.html#idm1874

Answer (score 0):

For a solution without duplicate objects and minimum added nodes, I would go like this:

With cusp node snapping switched on, select the tool for straight lines (Shift+F6) and draw a single segment exactly between the two corners.

[image]

(use Enter or right click to finish drawing) The new segment will look like this:

[image]

Select the original shape and move its segment to the right.

[image]

You can combine the two paths using Ctrl+K (Path > Combine) to have the whole thing in one path object.